# Multi-country website which doesn't use folders or subdomains

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a multiple country/city website where I don't redirect the user to a different subdomain/folder.

However, each country website is different and loads a different database, so I was wondering if I could have a folder for each website in the `public_html` folder, such as `public_html/orlando`, `public_html/nyc`, etc... and when a use picks a specific locale and language, it loads the website from that folder while the url still stays `www.example.com/`.

I've seen various ways of doing this but none of them solved the issue for me, that each website is inherently different as it loads a different db/articles.... etc.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you have tried, but you could store the language selection in a session (short lived) or a cookie (can persist longer) and read that value on every page to determine what database / articles should be used / fetched. By the way, I completely agree with @ColinMorelli and would not recommend this.

Comment: Don't do this. Use URLs (either subdomains or paths). It's better for your users (they can bookmark a locale specific version without having to change languages if/when they clear cookies) and it's _much_ better for SEO. Remember, just because there's a subdomain or path in the URL doesn't mean you need to have that directory structure. `mod_rewrite` is your friend.

Comment: To build on my prior comment. Imagine a search engine crawler goes to your page `www.mysite.com` and sees the content in English. Then, the crawler (as any crawler does) follows the links from that page. It finds a link to switch the site to french. It ends up at `www.mysite.com` where now the entire page is in French (and, even the translated content itself is different). What does the search engine index?

Comment: plz clear that how you knows about the city/country, does the user have to select or your code?

Comment: Hey Colin, thanks for your comment however there is no need for that in my website. My website is a venue map type site, where the only "article" is an "about us" page. Everything else is loaded via ajax anyways so the url doesn't change ever. You could say that I don't need a specific website for each locale, but I'm anticipating that certain things might be different in every country, which is why I need a separate website without actually changing urls.

Comment: Hey IOIO, I am thinking of having the specific site loaded automatically, with the user having the ability to change it.